# Forcing HD in embedded YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to force High Definition in embedded YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a workaround, but according to the YT documentation, the HD playback was included, but was deprecated:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Deprecated_Parameters

Don't think there is currently a way to enable HD playback by default.